# Makefile - undefined reference to function

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, c99

I have a sample project that I'm working with from a book "Learn C the hard way". But I can't make it compile.

I believe there is a problem with my Makefile. What I'm trying to do is build a library and then call some functions from it. But when compiling tests I get

```
cthehardway/dlib/tests/list_tests.c:36: undefined reference to `List_pop'
```

Here is my Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/libd.a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

# The Target Build
all: $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET) tests

dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@

$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p bin

# The Unit Tests
.PHONY: tests
tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
tests: $(TESTS)
    sh ./tests/runtests.sh

# The Cleaner
clean:
    rm -rf build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
    rm -f tests/tests.log 
    find . -name "*.gc*" -exec rm {} \;
    rm -rf `find . -name "*.dSYM" -print`

# The Install
install: all
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/

# The Checker
check:
    @echo Files with potentially dangerous functions.
    @egrep '[^_.>a-zA-Z0-9](str(n?cpy|n?cat|xfrm|n?dup|str|pbrk|tok|_)\
        |stpn?cpy|a?sn?printf|byte_)' $(SOURCES) || true
```

And here is the link to the project itself (it is small, couple of files);
The project is dlib folder, disregard outside files.

Only the tests target fails. The library builds fine.

https://github.com/Voley/cthehardway

Comment: What's the output from make right before the error occurs?

Comment: You can't do anything with Make until you know how to do it *without* Make. You should try building the test code "by hand" (i.e. from the command line, without Make). If it works, this is a Make problem, if it doesn't then it isn't. And either way you can came up with a simpler example.

Comment: @Beta still not building "by hand", giving same errors

Answer (score 1):

You're not including your library in the link of the test.

```
$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
```

You should include `$(TARGET)` in the bottom line.

At least, I think that's the case.   It's a dependency, so I assume you want to link with it.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I belive that is linker issue, since even if I enter everything manually it still fails.

Comment: @Dvole Make sure it's to the left of your $(OBJECTS)

Comment: oh. wow.   uh, make sure you're including the header file that defines those before your RUN_TESTS macro is invoked.  What you're seeing is a compile error, not a makefile issue or linking issue.

Comment: I am including it. Here is the project - https://github.com/Voley/c_troubles
As you can see I #include minunit.h at the top of the file https://github.com/Voley/c_troubles/blob/master/tests/list_tests.c

Comment: Hmm, you don't actually have a rule to make the tests.   I'm unsure how that's working.   Also, when you look at your command line that's building the tests, i'm unsure of how the options that include the libraries interact with gcc making an elf in one step.  Usually, when you call $(LD), the libraries need to be after the .o that needs them.    then you call $(CC) to do the whole thing....I dunno.   Try adding `-u List_push` that  to your OPTFLAGS and see if some of your errors go away.  If so, then it's a link order problem.